# Sorting out polynomials with roots of an undesireable magnitude

Tags: list-manipulation, polynomials

I have a list of polynomials `polys`.

I want a set of $f(x) \in$ `polys` which have roots strictly in $\{S^1,0\}$, with $S^1$ being the unit sphere.

They are all degree $n$, so I have crudely picked out those $f(x)$ such that the sum of the norms of the roots of $f$ is $\leq n$.

```
rts = Table[Values[{ToRules[Roots[Part[polys, i] == 0, x]]}], {i, 1, Length[polys]}] 

rtsAbsSum = Flatten[Table[Sum[Abs[Part[Part[rts, i], j]], {j, 1, Length[Part[rts, i]]}], {i, 1, Length[polys]}]]

parts = Select[Range[Length[polys]], Part[rtsAbsSum, #] <= n &]

polysIWant = Table[Part[polys, i], {i, parts}]
```

Now the list `polysIWant` contains the polynomials I want. However, it also contains many false positives.

This code is crude. What its doing:

1. Takes each polynomial of `polys` and replaces it with a list of its roots (multiplicity not counted.)
2. Adds together the `Abs` of the elements of each list.
3. Finds the polynomials whose sum of root norms is $\leq n$.

Is there an easier way? ie. Instead of summing roots, checking the inequality, etc., **how can I write  a program that tosses out the polynomials in `polys` with a root whose norm is neither $0$ nor $1$, and keeps the rest?**

Comment: If you have a function `roots` that gets the roots of a polynomial into a list form of consistent dimension, then why not something like: `Select[polys, Not[0!=Norm[roots[#]]!=1] &]`

Comment: I assume that by $S^1$ you mean that unit circle in the complex plane? So you are allowing complex roots?  Just for clarification.

Comment: Apparently there is something called the [Jury stability criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jury_stability_criterion) which you can use to determine if the roots of a polynomial are all inside the unit disk.

Comment: Are "roots of undesirable magnitude" related to "rodents of unusual size"?

Comment: R.O.U.M.s? I do not think they exist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an implementation of the [Jury stability criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jury_stability_criterion) (also known as the Jury-Marden criterion; there is also the Schur-Cohn criterion), which determines if the roots of a real-coefficient polynomial are all in the *open* unit disk.  The function returns `True` if all of the roots of the polynomial are in the open unit disk and returns `False` otherwise.

```
juryStabilityCheck[poly_, var_] := juryStabilityCheck[Reverse@CoefficientList[poly, var]]
juryStabilityCheck[coefs_List] := Module[
   {lst = coefs},
   If[First@lst < 0, lst = -lst];
   While[lst != {} && First@lst > 0, lst = lst - Last@lst/First@lst Reverse@lst // Most];
   lst == {}
  ]
```

Here is a polynomial whose roots are all in the open unit disk:

```
poly = (z - 0.5) (z - I/2) (z + I/2) (z - 0.3 I) (z + 0.3 I);
```

If we run the check on it, we get:

```
juryStabilityCheck[poly, z]
(* True *)
```

It works for any scalar multiple of that list:

```
juryStabilityCheck[-10 poly, z]
(* True *)
```

If some roots are outside the unit disk:

```
poly = (z - 0.5) (z - 3 I/2) (z + 3 I/2) (z - 0.3 I) (z + 0.3 I);
juryStabilityCheck[poly, z]
(* False *)
```

If a root is *on* the unit circle (i.e. the boundary of the unit disk), then the check finds that they are outside the open unit disk:

```
poly = (z - 1) (z - I/2) (z + I/2) (z - 0.3 I) (z + 0.3 I);
juryStabilityCheck[poly, z]
(* False *)
```

---

Now, if you want to include polynomials that have a root *on* the unit circle, the quick fix I've come up with is to "enlarge" the circle slightly by "shrinking" the z's.  You must choose a tolerance, and be okay with polynomials being included that have roots within this tolerance outside the unit circle.

Add to the code the definition

```
juryStabilityCheck[poly_, var_, tolerance_] := juryStabilityCheck[poly /. var -> var (1 + tolerance), var]
```

As an example:

```
poly = (z - 1) (z - I/2) (z + I/2) (z - 0.3 I) (z + 0.3 I) // Expand;
juryStabilityCheck[poly, z]
juryStabilityCheck[poly, z, 10^-9]
(* False *)
(* True *)
```

Of course, this will also include a polynomial whose roots are within the tolerance but outside the unit circle:

```
poly = (z - 1 + 10^-10) (z - I/2) (z + I/2) (z - 0.3 I) (z + 0.3 I);
juryStabilityCheck[poly, z, 10^-9]
(* True *)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is excellent. I've made a one-character change to your code that I believe was a typo (at least, everything worked AFTER I made it.)

Comment: For searching purposes: this is also sometimes referred to as the "Jury-Marden" criterion. There is also the more classical Schur-Cohn criterion for doing the same test.